# jQuery 'toggle' requiring two clicks

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this little menu thing I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/25/

The problem lies with the 'MISC' and 'MISC2' menus that slide open. When one is opened, the other needs to close, and the 'toggle' code I've pasted below works fine for the first two clicks, but then the menu items will require not one but two clicks to activate again. Any clues as how to keep it going with a single click?

For some reason, on touch devices the menus can't be closed either.

The code works everywhere with 'hover', but it really needs to be click-activated.

Here's what I have:

```
function mainmenu(){

    $('.menu ul').css({display: "none"});

    $('.menu li.sub').toggle(function(){
        $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(200);
    },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(200);
    });

    $('.sub-menu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); 

};

$(document).ready(function(){                  
    mainmenu();
});
```

Comment: That version of `toggle()` was deprecated in 1.7, and removed in 1.9

Comment: Oh.. Any workaround suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested, but try something more like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    $('.menu ul').hide();

    $('.menu li.sub').click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul:first').slideToggle(200)
               .end().siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work great too. Chosen as answer due to simplicity. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ptz9F/

I would say, use some classes and specify steps the right way :)

Only my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    $('.menu ul.sub-menu').css({display: "none"});
    $('.menu li.sub > a').click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent('li'),
            $sub = $('.sub-menu', $parent);

        if (!$sub.hasClass('slided-down'))
        {
            // this sub is not visible
            $('.sub-menu.slided-down').slideUp(200).removeClass('slided-down');
            $sub.slideDown(200).addClass('slided-down');
        }
        else
        {
            // this sub is visible
            $sub.slideUp(200).removeClass('slided-down');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I voted your solution up but selected the other one as the answer due to the solution's simplicity. Soz :( For those with a similar issue though, both solutions work great.